# Unable to access application after deploying on Tomcat using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have recently started using Maven build tool for learning purpose.
I've previously made a small web application which was working fine on deploying directly on Tomcat 7.0.67 using Eclipse Indigo.
After I converted my web project into a Maven project and deploying it in the Tomcat server, I am unable to access it. When I check my Manager App tab, I can see my .war is deployed successfully.

[Tomcat Manager App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5O2E.png)

LearningJSPv01..this is the maven project context.

edit: I just observed that while trying to add other web project resource to server, I am not getting the Maven project name

Comment: is the context-path set correctly on the server in eclipse server tab? Doubleclick your server, switch to "Modules" tab and check "Path"

Comment: I added the context path as suggested but it isn't working @RaphaelRoth